# Text of the textbox is always empty on a customized styling in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, styles

Hey I'm designing a new style for a textbox in my WPF application using XAML codes. The textbox is a combination of textbox and textblock, I used the textblock to show name of the textbox when the text is null, and disappears when the text is filled, but there is a problem when I run the app and fill something in the textbox it seems that it's working properly but in the backend when I want to access the textbox Text it's null even though it's filled!!!!
Am I doing something wrong from the base or I missed something to do.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
           x:Key="TextBoxTheme">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="10"
                            Background="#353340"
                            Width="200"
                            Height="40">
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1"/>
                            <TextBox Margin="1" 
                                     Text="{TemplateBinding Property=Text}"
                                     BorderThickness="0"
                                     Background="Transparent"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                     Padding="5"
                                     Foreground="#CFCFCF"
                                     x:Name="textBox"/>
                            <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding Name}"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                       Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"
                                       FontSize="11"
                                       Foreground="DarkGray">
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox}" Value="">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `TextBox` in the `ControlTemplate` for the `TextBox`. What is about `UserControl` with a content, which you have in the `ControlTemplate`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving the TextBox an area to display its contents, you have overlapped it on top with another TextBox.
To display its content, the TextBox looks in the Template for `ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"`.

Try a Template like this:

```xml
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="PART_TextBlock" Text="{TemplateBinding Name}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                                          Focusable="false"
                                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Text"
                                         Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_TextBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this on the YouTube video comments where this question code comes from. In the template xaml file do the following:

Repalce This:
`Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"`

With This:
`Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

I was able to capture text from the **TextChanged** event after this change.

Answer (score -1):

If you check [the documentation for TemplateBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) you'll see it's just syntactic sugar for a *one-way* RelativeSource binding to the templated parent, so all you need to do is change your TextBox binding to make it two-way:

```
Text="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Also, I disagree with the comment above about this not being a good idea, one of the whole purposes of WPF's templating system is to make it possible to template existing controls e.g. for redistribution of libraries etc. That said, I don't think `Name` is the best property to use for your hint text, if for no other reason than the fact that it doesn't allow spaces. A much better solution would be to use an [attached property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). For a quick-and-dirty solution there's also the `Tag` property, which you're free to use for whatever you want.

Comment: I think you are wrong about TempleBinding.
This question has already been raised more than once, on the Internet you can easily find relevant topics.
This one-way binding was intentionally done to avoid the influence of the Control Template on the Logic (Behavior) of the control.
And in a properly implemented Template, there should be no Mode=TwoWay bindings to element properties.
The reason for the Template problem (from the author of the topic) is different.